# UITableViewCell loaded from Xib always has Nil values

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib

Here is my table view code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelCell: IconAndTitleTableViewCell!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "IconAndTitleTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "iconAndLabelCell")

        labelCell.titleView.text = "Test"    
    }        
}
```

Here is the table view:

[image: table view screenshot]

Here is the Xib file:

[image: xib file]

And yet I keep getting the error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

when trying to set the labelCell.

Its fields are nil. But why are they nil? I have clearly registered it with the table.

Comment: at what point in the code are you getting the error?

Comment: labelCell.titleView.text = "Test"

Comment: At that point you haven't instantiated a labelCell.  You have registered it for reuse as a dynamic cell but that's all.  You seem to be mixing up dynamic and static cells.  There's a clue in the method signature that this is for dynamic - `forCellReuseIdentifier` - as reuse is not relevant for static cells.  If you'd done the cell in IB not a XIB this would work.

Answer (score 0):

You could not make an `IBOutlet` of reusable elements like cell.
you need:

1. conform to `UITableViewDataSource` delegate method and implement all his required methods
   for ex:

   ```
   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
   }
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return 1
   }
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "", for: indexPath)
       return cell
   }
   ```
2. you can access to you cell inside `cellForRowAt` method
3. or you can access to your cell using method tableView.cellForRow(at: indexpath)

Answer (score -1):

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"iconAndLableCell" owner:self options:nil];
labelCell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
labelCell.titleView.text = @"Test";
```